# How to implement non explicit 1:1 relationship with Doctrine?

Tags: php, model, schema, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, Inventory and, say, Stuff. Inventory is used to store data common to Stuff and other tables. The way the DBA envisioned this working would be with us inserting the Inventory table and then using the generated ID to insert the Stuff table.

How can I implement this scenario using Doctrine 2? I'm tempted to just add a 1:1 relationship on the model but I'm not sure I can convince the DBA to change the database.

Answer (score 1):

With the workaround described here http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#foreign-keys-as-identifiers you should be able to get the DBAs schema working. With version 2.1 of Doctrine (or the current master) you can use the new foreign key as identifier feature to get it working.

However if you are not using Sequences of Oracle/Postgresql you need to flush operations for this (persist parent, flush, associate and persist child, flush)